# how to change ipython notebook directory to save the notebooks in dropbox?

Tags: ipython, dropbox, anaconda

I've installed anaconda on windows 7 and I would like to save my notebooks on dropbox to have easy access from another pc. How can I change the directory in which my notebooks saved there?

Comment: In your `ipython_notebook_config.py` [config file](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html#python-config-files), you can set `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` to the directory where you want the notebook server to run.

Comment: Thanks, I also have problem with installing IR kernel on my jupyter drive. I would appreciate if help me.

Comment: Please post a new question for that - thanks!